# Installed package stealing namespace

Tags: python, namespaces, package

I'm developing a package "jw.data" in  Python 2.7.9, with a namespace of *jw* and a package *data* in in. I have put the canonical

```
try:
    __import__('pkg_resources').declare_namespace(__name__)
except ImportError:
    from pkgutil import extend_path
__path__ = extend_path(__path__, __name__)
```

in `jw/__init__.py`. When I run `./setup.py develop` (in setup.py I have put `namespace_packages=['jw']`), then I have "jw" in `jw.data.egg-info/namespace_packages.txt`. Doing a

```
import jw.data
import jw.data.model
```

just works fine. So I guess I have set up the namespace package correctly.

Now I have written a package "jw.util", also in namespace *jw*, with a package *util* in it. As soon as I install it, importing *jw.data* or anything below it fails:

```
>>> import jw.data
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named data
```

After uninstalling *jw.util* it works again.

I used *jw.util* elsewhere, but not yet in a package within the *jw* namespace. It looks like *jw.util* is reserving the *jw* namespace.

I had the same problem with another namespace. There I noticed the package name in setup.py is just the same as the namespace plus package. I renamed all the packages from "namespace.package*x*" to "namespace-package*x*", and astonishingly enough it worked. I tried the same with *jw.util* and *jw.data*, but here that trick doesn't work. And I don't really believe the package name in setup.py has anything to do with the package hierarchy it contains, or has it?

Anyway, anybody got an idea what's going on here?

Answer (score 1):

Seems to be a long-known bug in Python.

But there's a solution in https://github.com/pypa/setuptools/issues/250:

Put simply, append

```
;import pkg_resources; pkg_resources.fixup_namespace_packages('')
```

to the single line in *module*-nspkg.pth of the competing package in site-packages. The semicolon is required.

Comment: Note, that this bug has been fixed in setuptools 31.0.0: https://github.com/pypa/setuptools/commit/6f5dc38012824dc3d104356d023ec3c959bbb586